# Find a formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that $y=\{x\}$

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Please check if my solution is correct:
$$\phi(x,y)=\forall x \exists y : (x\dot{\in}y \leftrightarrow \nexists z \neq x : z\dot{\in} y)$$
Basically, I'm trying to say that the set $y$ has $x$ as its element and no other element $z$ different from $x$. Thanks!

Edit, second attempt:
$$\phi(x,y)=x\dot{\in}y \land \not\exists z \neq x : z\dot{\in} y$$

Comment: why do you need the initial quantifiers?

Comment: Also replace $\leftrightarrow$ with $\wedge$

Comment: @whoisit Oh, I totally mixed the questions up, since later I have to prove it from ZFC. Now it should look better.

Comment: Also what do you mean by "$\;:\;$"? - it is not a standard logic operator. $\land$ or $\implies$?

Comment: Your formula isn't a formula in $x,y$ since $x,y$ are "bound" in your expression. For example, what is $\phi(\emptyset,\emptyset)?$

Comment: I suggest rigorous treatment of the symbols - and not using shortcuts. Restrict the symbols of use to only  $\lnot, \land, \lor, \implies, \forall, \exists$ and $\in$. Use $()$ to disambiguate scope. \
Do **NOT** use things such as $\nexists$ or $:$. Your confusion stems from this.

Also see BrianO's comment on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest rigorous treatment of the symbols - and not using shortcuts. Restrict the symbols of use to only  $\lnot, \land, \lor, \implies, \forall, \exists$ and $\in$. Use $()$ to disambiguate scope. 
Do **NOT** use things such as $\nexists$ or $:$. Your confusion stems from this.

Now, with respect to this question, I would write it as:
$\phi(x, y)= (x \in y) \;\bigwedge\; \bigg(\forall z \; (z\in y \implies z=x)\bigg) $

The second attempt is closer to correct but not entirely correct

Let's try using some equivalences.

This is what I say: 
$
\begin{align}
\forall z \; (z\in y \implies z=x) 
&\equiv \lnot \big( \lnot \forall z \; (z\in y \implies z=x)\big)  \\
&\equiv \lnot \big( \exists z \; \lnot (z\in y \implies z=x)\big)  \\
&\equiv \lnot \big( \exists z \; \ (z\in y \land z \neq x)\big)  \\
\end{align}
$

This is what you say: 
$
\begin{align}
\lnot \exists z  \;(z\neq x \implies z \in y)  
&\equiv \lnot \exists z  \;(\lnot z\neq x \lor z \in y) \\
&\equiv \lnot \exists z  \;( z = x \lor z \in y) \\
&\equiv \forall z  \;\lnot( z = x \lor z \in y) \\
&\equiv \forall z  \;\lnot( z = x \lor z \in y) \\
&\equiv \forall z  \;\lnot( z = x \lor z \in y) \\
&\equiv \forall z  \; (z \neq x \land z \not\in y) 
\end{align}
$

Can you spot your mistake?

Comment: Not sure I understand, aren't $\forall$ and $\nexists$ basically equivalent to each other? Or is it that my formula states that no element in the structure is equal to $x$, implying that no such set exists?

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer The problem isn't in use of $\nexists$, it is in the use of $\implies, \land$ or $\lor$ ; $\;\;\;\;$
Where you use "$:$" (which I suppose is $\implies$) , you should use $\land$

Comment: @averagemathenjoyer and yes, as it is - your formula currently means no element in the structure is equal to $x$

Comment: @OP No: $\forall$ is equivalent to $\neg \exists \neg$, and $\exists$ is equivalent to $\neg \forall \neg$.